# shell_exec throwing warning php

Tags: php, shell

I am running the following command through shell_exec but I'm getting the following Warning. The command isn't executing on the server.

```
$output=shell_exec ("awk -F'\t' '/\[Data\]/{f=1;next} /^$/{f=0} f{gsub(/\t/,",");print}' 1.tsv > 2.csv");

Warning: Wrong parameter count for shell_exec() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/output/u.php on line 3
```

I tried using system and passthru but they result in fatal errors.

Whats wrong? I'm passing only one parameter in shell_exec.

Comment: Escape internal quotes.. Like this `f{gsub(/\t/,\",\")`

Comment: You need an editor with syntax hightlighting.

Comment: You have unescaped double quotes `"` in your argument, making it two strings

Comment: @mario you are right.. I'm using pico.. Couldn't catch this small thing..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to escape the string, there are `","` in your sting:

```
$output=shell_exec ("awk -F'\t' '/\[Data\]/{f=1;next} /^$/{f=0} f{gsub(/\t/,\",\");print}' 1.tsv > 2.csv");
```

Comment: Thanks.. stupid me.. I couldn't see this small thing. I'm using pico as my text editor.